# On $3+\sqrt{11+\sqrt{11+\sqrt{11+\sqrt{11+\dots}}}}=\phi^4$ and friends

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, nested-radicals, golden-ratio, lucas-numbers

Let $\phi$ be the *golden ratio*. We know it has a beautiful infinite nested radical,

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}}=\phi$$

However, it is also the case that,

$$3+\sqrt{11+\sqrt{11+\sqrt{11+\sqrt{11+\dots}}}}=\phi^4$$

$$5+\sqrt{31+\sqrt{31+\sqrt{31+\sqrt{31+\dots}}}}=\phi^5$$

$$\tfrac{17}2+\sqrt{\tfrac{319}4+\sqrt{\tfrac{319}4+\sqrt{\tfrac{319}4+\sqrt{\tfrac{319}4+\dots}}}}=\phi^6$$

---

**Q:** How do we show that, in general

$$a_n+\sqrt{b_n+\sqrt{b_n+\sqrt{b_n+\sqrt{b_n+\dots}}}}=\phi^n$$

where,

$$a_n = \frac{L_n-1}2,\quad b_n = \frac{5F_n^2-1}4$$

with *Lucas numbers* $L_n$ and *Fibonacci numbers* $F_n$?

Comment: I knew the expression $5F_n^2$ looked familiar. Turns out $L_n^2-5F_n^2 = 4(-1)^n$, so $a_n,b_n$ can be expressed purely in terms of the Lucas numbers.

Comment: This article on the  [Mandelbrot Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) might be if use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we plug in the given formulas we get the famous formula. We note:
$$\sqrt{b_n+x}=x \Rightarrow x=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4b_n}}{2}=\frac{1+F_n\sqrt{5}}{2};$$
Hence:
$$\frac{L_n-1}{2}+\frac{1+F_n\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{L_n+F_n\sqrt{5}}{2}=\phi^n.$$
This is a famous formula that relates the two sequences. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number